# How to create folder contain image in Android Studio

Tags: android, resources

How to create 2 folder: Asia, Africa contain many .png image inside?
Thank all!!!
[image: Resource contain folder Asia..]

Comment: Why don't just use `drawable`or `mipmap` resources ?

Comment: Put your images inside "Drawable" folder.

Comment: Why are you asking? You already created them!

Answer (score 3):

You must include images to drawable or mipmap (icon) not another folder in res. 
Or you can create assets folder and create 2 folders (Asian, Africa) to this folder and paste images into 2 folders you need.

[image: this image]